# Why can't I deliver emails using Sidekiq 3.3 and Rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendmail, sidekiq, exim

I am currently using Rails 4.1.9 and Sidekiq 3.3.0 on a production environment (on a private physical server).

When I try to send emails using the `delay` method from Sidekiq using:

```
UserMailer.delay.new_user(user)
```

it happens that the `mailer` queue works correctly, the mail is dequeued and rendered, but it's not delivered. This is the only log I get on the `sidekiq.log` file:

```
2015-01-23T17:29:37.107Z 11266 TID-zo3e4 Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-37f667c9ab5d446e07655ed6 INFO: start
  Rendered user_mailer/new_user.html.haml within layouts/mail (0.8ms)
2015-01-23T17:29:37.117Z 11266 TID-zo3e4 Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-37f667c9ab5d446e07655ed6 INFO: done: 0.01 sec
```

Instead, if I call the usual method:

```
UserMailer.new_user(user).deliver
```

the mail gets rendered **and** delivered.

The app is configured to use `sendmail` for sending emails and I have `exim4` installed and working on the server.

Is there any way I can fix this problem?

Comment: Show us your `new_user` method. 99% chance it's because you aren't setting the From: attribute.

Comment: I am setting it using an email interceptor. Can this be the issue? I mean, I am using a default `from` setting for every email but I do this in the interceptor. Is there any chance that Sidekiq is ignoring this passage?

Comment: Here's the logic, you can determine why your mail message isn't `deliver`ed: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/extensions/action_mailer.rb#L20

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this. Please, add a detailed answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidekiq currently requires the mail object to have the (To | Bcc | Cc) and From attributes set.

This will be fixed in 3.3.1 where it won't check these attributes.